# firebase authentication with email and username and password

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am wondering if there is the ability to sign in with email and user id + password , I have a project that I want user to add a unique number ( actually it is our work identify number provided by our company ) to be able to sign in to the program will stay private to company employment .

I need the firebase authentication to refuse login even if email and password are correct but the user id is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the database to check if the id is the same or not.

You can create the following database:

```
users
   userId
      userCompanyId : id
      email         : email@gmail.com
```

So you can first authenticate the user based on his email and password and then, check if the id or unique number entered by the user is the same as the one in the database:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                      // retrieve Id from database and check if it is the same
                } else {
                    //sign in failed
                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is indeed the common approach. You could even consider implementing a custom provider for this, although you'll have to store more information yourself, since the Admin SDK can't verify the credentials for you in that case.

Comment: can you help me with my login activity to be able to do the check for me, please? I added my login and register activities in the post, regards.

Comment: please check my codes up to and tell me where should I put the creat order to make the ID in the database and where to put the codes to check while logging in.

Comment: please add your code in the question and not in my answer